# Appium Doctor does not recognize environment variables in ~/.bash_profile

Tags: appium, appium-ios, appium-android

Adding these environment variables to my `~/.bash_profile`

```
ANDROID_HOME=/Users/username/Library/Android/sdk
PATH=${PATH}:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform_tools
JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)
PATH=${JAVA_HOME}/bin:$PATH
```

does not prevent these warnings when running Appium Doctor:

```
ANDROID_HOME is NOT set!
JAVA_HOME is NOT set!
adb could not be found because ANDROID_HOME is NOT set!
android could not be found because ANDROID_HOME is NOT set!
emulator could not be found because ANDROID_HOME is NOT set!
Bin directory for $JAVA_HOME is not set
```

Instead, I must manually add the environment variables with `export` every instance I open a new terminal

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/username/Library/Android/sdk
export PATH=${PATH}:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform_tools
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)
export PATH=${JAVA_HOME}/bin:$PATH
```

Any idea why Appium does not recognize the environment variables defined in the `~/.bash_profile`?

Thanks.

Comment: silly question: did you restart terminal after modifying `.bash_profile`?

Comment: I don't remember. Can you do `source ~/.bash_profile` without restarting the Terminal like in Linux?

Comment: either way is to restart or to execute `source` command

Answer (score 4):

I had to export the variables from within the `~/.bash_profile` for the variables to persist, not from the command line

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/username/Library/Android/sdk
export PATH=${PATH}:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform_tools
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)
export PATH=${JAVA_HOME}/bin:$PATH
```

Comment: Upon adding the environment variables, restart the machine